# Error : npm install ERROR "No Valid versions available for dateFormat"?

Tags: node.js, npm, google-compute-engine, centos7, date-format

I use google cloud engine VM instances is CentOS7. I clone the Node project from git and try to run but

> Error : Cannot find module 'dateFormat'

then I have tried to install dateFormat on CentOS7 with

> npm install dateFormat

but display error this

```
npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No valid versions available for dateFormat

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-05-24T04_43_53_179Z-debug.log
```

How to fix them ?

Comment: There is no dateFormat package, try npm install dateformat. Might be the package you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your spelling of date**F**ormat, should be all lowercase

```
$ npm install dateformat
```

I just ran both on a vm centos7 with your spelling of uppercase F and all lowercase. Using all lowercase works.
see npm page https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat
while the require seems to use the uppercase F as

```
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
```

the actual install package is all lowercase

If doesn't work try:
What version of npm are you running?
Try removing and reinstalling npm
What project are you running from github?

Comment: I tried to use lowercase follow you answer. It ‘s work. thank you but I understand isn’t occur the problem on  Windows.